# how to call the directive inside the custom directive template in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

**Problem**

If I choose the particular company name, I need to show the bank details of the company and append it to the HTML.

**Code**

```
(function(angular){
var app = angular.module('mypurchase',[]);
app.controller('purchasectrl',['$scope',function ($scope) {
    var obj = '<%-JSON.stringify(companiesdata)%>';
    var companydetails = JSON.parse(obj);
    $scope.companydetails =  companydetails;
    $scope.getcompany = function(details){
       $scope.showdiv = false;
       $scope.firm_name = details.company_name;
    }
}]);
app.directive('allCompanyDetails',function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA', // Element directive
        template: '<div ng-repeat="details in companydetails | filter : firm_name" ng-click="getcompany(details);">{{ details.company_name }}</div><companybankdetails></companybankdetails>'
    };
});

app.directive('companybankdetails',function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA', // Element directive
        template: '<companybankdetails></companybankdetails>',
        $scope.bankname = details.bank_name;



    };
});

   })(angular);
```